# How to update Model with the correct value type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code that fetch data from internet:

```
Future fetchCfo(String barCode, String url) async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url + barCode));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    responseBody.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == null) {
        responseBody.update(key, (value) => "");
      }
    });
    return CfoModel.fromJson(responseBody);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And I need to replace the null values ​​according to their type, for example if a field that was supposed to be an integer returns a null I need to replace it with 0, if a field that was supposed to be a list returns a null I need to replace it with a list empty []; and I don't know how to do this, my code replaces Strings but if a null appears in an int field, the code breaks.

For example, my model:

```
 String? interfaceStatus;
    bool? trasnP;
    int? id;
    String? name;
    String? date;
    bool? requiredStatus;
    int? numberOf;
    int? numberRegion;
    List? parameters;
```

In case numberRegion returns a null, I need to replace with `0`;
In case Transp returns a null, I need to replace with `false`;
in case name returns a null, I need to replace with empty String `""`;

Response I'm getting:

```
{
   "interfaceStatus":"ok",
   "trasnP":false,
   "id":null,
   "name":null,
   "date":null,
   "requiredStatus":true,
   "numberOf":23,
   "numberRegion":27,
   "parameters":null
}
```

What I want to return:

```
{
   "interfaceStatus":"ok",
   "trasnP":false,
   "id":0,
   "name":"",
   "date":"",
   "requiredStatus":true,
   "numberOf":23,
   "numberRegion":27,
   "Parameters":[
      
   ]
}
```

Anyone has a solution for this ?

Comment: Can you share your response as well?

Comment: Added response example

Comment: Okay but you have to put the replacement value manually is it okay for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not updating any values in the responseBody just leave them as null but in the `fromJson`  function you can give default values with the `??` operator such as:

```
  fromJson(Map response) {

    return CfoModel(
      id: response[id] ?? 0,
      array: response[array_element] ?? [],
  );
}
```

Comment: is there a way to automatize this process ? I have more than 1000 values in 11 services to add default values

Comment: if it's only string int or List you can loop through all the keys and do something like if(key is String && key == null) key = "";   
else if (key is List && key == null) key = []; etc...